# Why is this image not being added to my scrollview?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

Why is this image not being added to my `UIScrollView`? A white screen is being displayed:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 1, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * self.urlArray.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: Can you : NSLog(@"self.scrollView.frame.size.width * self.urlArray.count : %f, self.scrollView.frame.size.height : %f",self.scrollView.frame.size.width * self.urlArray.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height); this and print it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
```

Ans also give proper `contentSize` of `UIScrollView` and add `UIScrollView` to your `UIView`

Comment: may be problem in CGRectMake or OP forget to add ScView to UIView

Comment: It was the contentSize and adding the UIScrollview that fixed the problem if I can remember correctly. Also I had to move code from viewDidload to viewWillAppear.